# file mysteriously vanished with no trace github

Tags: wordpress, github

I think I'm going a bit crazy over here.
I modified an .htaccess file and created a PR on github, but it showed I was freshly creating the file. 
That can't be because I'm 90% sure I'm only modifying it and didn't create it, because I don't know how to write a rewrite rule for wordpress and that is what's inside of it before.

My question is, could there be any way a file would be deleted from a repository without any logs of it. I couldn't even find the file in any of the branches and commit history. I'm completely lost on this. Maybe I'm the crazy one and just created the file.

I do have a bit of proof it did exist. There was an entry in .gitignore for the exact file path of the .htaccess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There was an entry in .gitignore for the exact file path of the .htaccess.

There you go. It was in `.gitignore` which means... it was ignored!

Therefore it was never part of the git repo (but could still exist in your local file system)

Now that it is removed from `.gitignore` it is now being added from your local file system into the git repo.

---

For a little best practice on your PR, it could be useful to reviewers if you made one commit where you just add the `.htaccess` as it stands today, then a second commit where you actually 'change' the file.

Comment: Thank you! and thank you for the tip to properly do a PR when handling this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to give an answer to this just in case someone else ran into this issue.

Turns out the .htaccess was automatically put it from apache when I installed wordpress for this project. The rest of the group of people don't need this file since they're using nginx which is why it was in .gitignore.

So that is why the repository doesn't have the .htaccess file and never did. I was the idiot for freaking out and assumed it was a github issue when it wasn't.  Oh well. Now I know.